# Resume a WHILE loop from where it stopped SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I have a while loop query that I only want to run until 11PM everyday - I'm aware this can be achieved with a WAITFOR statement, and then just END the query.

However, on the following day, once I re-run my query, I want it to continue from where it stopped on the last run. So I'm thinking of creating a log table that will contain the last processed ID.

How can I achieve this?

```
DECLARE @MAX_Value BIGINT  = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM dbo.TableA )

DECLARE @MIN_Value BIGINT = ( SELECT MIN(ID) FROM dbo.TableA )

            WHILE (@MIN_Value < @MAX_Value )
            BEGIN

                INSERT INTO dbo.MyResults
                /* Do some processing*/
                ….
                ….
                ….

                SET @MIN_Value = MIN_Value + 1

            /*I only want the above processing to run until 11PM*/

            /* Once it’s 11PM, I want to save the last used @MIN_Value 
            into my LoggingTable (dbo.Logging) and kill the above processing.*/

        /* Once I re-run the query I want my processing to restart from the
 above @MIN_Value which is recorded in dbo.Logging */

            END
```

Comment: Before answering this question... It appears to me that you are trying to use a wrong kind of solution for your actual problem. What is the problem are you trying to solve by implementing this WHILE loop? Are you running SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQL Server. I'm aware I could just create a job to do this. But I want to solve it using T-SQL.

Comment: What is the actual problem your loop is supposed to solve? What is the use case (business scenario)? Are you processing something/calculating stuff?

Ok, got it, will answer with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I do not recommend using WHILE loops in SQL Server but considering the comment that you want a solution in SQL, here you go:

```
-- First of all, I strongly recommend using a different way of assigning variable values to avoid scenarios with the variable being NULL when the table is empty, also you can do it in a single select.

-- Also, if something started running at 10:59:59 it will let the processing for the value finish and will not simply rollback at 11.

CREATE TABLE dbo.ProcessingValueLog (
    LogEntryId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    LastUsedValue BIGINT NOT NULL,
    LastUsedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
    CompletedProcessing BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
)

DECLARE @MAX_Value BIGINT = 0;
DECLARE @MIN_Value BIGINT = 0;

SELECT
    @MIN_Value = MIN(ID),
    @MAX_Value = MAX(ID)
FROM
    dbo.TableA

SELECT TOP 1
    @MIN_Value = LastUsedValue
FROM
    dbo.ProcessingValueLog
WHERE
    CompletedProcessing = 1
ORDER BY
    LastUsedDateTime DESC

DECLARE @CurrentHour TINYINT = HOUR(GETDATE());
DECLARE @LogEntryID BIGINT;

WHILE (@MIN_Value < @MAX_Value AND @CurrentHour < 23)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.ProcessingValueLog (LastUsedValue)
    VALUE(@MIN_Value)

    SELECT @LogEntryID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    // Do some processing...

    SET @MIN_Value = @MIN_Value + 1;

    UPDATE dbo.ProcessingValueLog
    SET CompletedProcessing = 1
    WHERE LogEntryId = @LogEntryID

    SET @CurrentHour = HOUR(GETDATE())
END
```

Comment: What is `CURRENT_IDENTITY()`? Did you mean `IDENT_CURRENT()`? As a rule, [`Scope_Identity()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) is a much better choice as it is limited to the current session and scope. An alternative (that is overkill in this instance) is an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.

Comment: @HABO Oops, I meant SCOPE_IDENTITY()... Was typing in the SO editor, did not even check the syntax. Fixed, thanks for pointing out.